# MySQL partitioning approach for addresses table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that contains 100 million+ addresses. The table structure is:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`zip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`addressable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

What I need help in deciding what type of partitioning to implement. Should i use RANGE partitioning on the creation date, or HASH partitioning on the id column, or some other type ?

Comment: The answer really depends on what type of queries you will be running.

Comment: Why do you want to partition? If it's because you have slow queries, show them. If another reason, tell us. Right now, the answer is "don't partition".

Answer (score 1):

How many zipcodes have you seen with 255 characters?  Are you using utf8?  How many zipcodes have anything not-ascii?

Partitioning does *not* help performance.  I have never seen a use case for HASH partitioning that could not be done better via an index.

RANGE may be useful if you are purging "old" data or doing 2-dimensional lookups.

Let's see your queries.  And think about the INDEX(es) you would use.  Think, especially, about "composite" indexes.